# Site I/o usage and physical memory usage max when user try to download file around 1gb

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing a problem when I download a file around 1 GB the URL is stuck and the cpanel I/O usage and physical memory usage is maxed and site is stuck.

After I stop URL reload the I/O usage and physical memory usage turns normal in 2-5 seconds.

Here is my file download code. What's wrong in the code that causes this problem?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000);

class Download_shared_link extends CI_Controller  { 
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper("file");
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('zip');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $logged_id = $this->session->userdata('userid');
            if($logged_id != 1)
            {   
                $this->db->where('sharing_link_user_id',$logged_id);
            }

            $this->db->join('users','user_id = sharing_link_user_id');
            $data['recored'] = $this->db->get('sharing_link')->result();

            $this->load->view('admin/shared_link/list',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect(site_url());
        }
    }

    public function downloadLink($path=''){
        $data['downloadLink'] = $path;
        $this->load->view('admin/google_captcha/shared_link_Page',$data);
    }

    function captcha_check($str) {
        if (!$this->input->post('captcha_chk', true)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check', 'The Captcha check required.');
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->input->post('captcha_chk', true) !== $this->input->post('ran', true)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check', 'Captcha Not Matched!.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function download($path = '') 
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('string');


        return $this->load->view('admin/shared_link/unlock-file-view', array('filename' => $path));



        //validation check      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha_chk', 'Captcha', 'trim|required|callback_captcha_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('admin/shared_link/captcha-check', array('filename' => $path));
        } else {
            $path = base64_decode(urldecode($path));

            $this->db->where('sharing_link_path', $path);
            $chk_path = $this->db->get('sharing_link');

            if ($chk_path->num_rows()) {
                $path_info = $chk_path->row_array();

                if ($path_info['sharing_link_active'] == 'yes') {
                    //$access_time = $path_info['sharing_link_time'];

                    /*if ($access_time >= date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {*/
                        $filepath = './drive/' . $path;

                        if (false && is_dir('./drive/' . $path)) {
                            $source = './drive/' . $path;
                            $base_name = basename($source);

                            $this->zip->add_dir($base_name);
                            $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

                            foreach ($files as $file) {
                                $file_path = realpath($file);
                                if (is_dir($file_path)) {
                                    $total_download_file++;
                                    $this->zip->add_dir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $base_name . '/' . $file . '/'));
                                } else if (is_file($file)) {
                                    $total_download_file++;
                                    $this->zip->add_data(str_replace($source . '/', '', $base_name . '/' . $file), file_get_contents($file));
                                }
                            }

                            $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->db->dbprefix('sharing_link') . ' SET sharing_download = sharing_download + 1 WHERE sharing_link_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_id'] . ' AND sharing_link_user_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_user_id']);

                            $this->zip->download($base_name . '.zip');
                        } elseif (file_exists($filepath)) {

                            $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->db->dbprefix('sharing_link') . ' SET sharing_download = sharing_download + 1 WHERE sharing_link_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_id'] . ' AND sharing_link_user_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_user_id']);

                            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filepath) . '"');
                            header('Expires: 0');
                            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                            header('Pragma: public');
                            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
                            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
                            readfile($filepath);
                            exit;
                        }
                    /*} else {
                        $this->db->where('sharing_link_id', $path_info['sharing_link_id']);
                        $this->db->delete('sharing_link');
                        redirect(site_url());
                    }*/
                } else {
                    echo "<p>This Link Not Active !</p>";
                }
            } else {
                redirect(site_url());
            }
        }
    }

    public function captcha($path = '') {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('string');


        $path = base64_decode(urldecode($path));

        //validation check      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha_chk', 'Captcha', 'trim|required|callback_captcha_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('admin/shared_link/captcha-check', array('filename' => $path));
        } else {
            //$path = base64_decode(urldecode($path));

            $this->db->where('sharing_link_path', $path);
            $chk_path = $this->db->get('sharing_link');

            if ($chk_path->num_rows()) {
                $path_info = $chk_path->row_array();

                if ($path_info['sharing_link_active'] == 'yes') {
                    //$access_time = $path_info['sharing_link_time'];

                    /*if ($access_time >= date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {*/
                        $filepath = './drive/' . $path;

                        if (false && is_dir('./drive/' . $path)) {
                            $source = './drive/' . $path;
                            $base_name = basename($source);

                            $this->zip->add_dir($base_name);
                            $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

                            foreach ($files as $file) {
                                $file_path = realpath($file);
                                if (is_dir($file_path)) {
                                    $total_download_file++;
                                    $this->zip->add_dir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $base_name . '/' . $file . '/'));
                                } else if (is_file($file)) {
                                    $total_download_file++;
                                    $this->zip->add_data(str_replace($source . '/', '', $base_name . '/' . $file), file_get_contents($file));
                                }
                            }

                            $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->db->dbprefix('sharing_link') . ' SET sharing_download = sharing_download + 1 WHERE sharing_link_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_id'] . ' AND sharing_link_user_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_user_id']);

                            $this->zip->download($base_name . '.zip');
                        } elseif (file_exists($filepath)) {

                            $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->db->dbprefix('sharing_link') . ' SET sharing_download = sharing_download + 1 WHERE sharing_link_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_id'] . ' AND sharing_link_user_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_user_id']);

                            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filepath) . '"');
                            header('Expires: 0');
                            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                            header('Pragma: public');
                            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
                            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
                            readfile($filepath);
                            exit;
                        }
                    /*} else {
                        $this->db->where('sharing_link_id', $path_info['sharing_link_id']);
                        $this->db->delete('sharing_link');
                        redirect(site_url());
                    }*/
                } else {
                    echo "<p>This Link Not Active !</p>";
                }
            } else {
                redirect(site_url());
            }
        }
    }

    public function download_dis($path = '') {
        $org_path = $path;
        $path = base64_decode(urldecode($path));


        $this->db->where('sharing_link_path', $path);
        $chk_path = $this->db->get('sharing_link');

        if ($chk_path->num_rows()) {
            $path_info = $chk_path->row_array();

            if ($path_info['sharing_link_active'] == 'yes') {
                $access_time = $path_info['sharing_link_time'];

                if ($access_time >= date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
                    $filepath = './drive/' . $path;

                    if (false && is_dir('./drive/' . $path)) {
                        $source = './drive/' . $path;
                        $base_name = basename($source);

                        $this->zip->add_dir($base_name);
                        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

                        // print_r($files);exit;

                        foreach ($files as $file) {
                            $file_path = realpath($file);
                            if (is_dir($file_path)) {
                                $total_download_file++;
                                $this->zip->add_dir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $base_name . '/' . $file . '/'));
                            } else if (is_file($file)) {
                                $total_download_file++;
                                $this->zip->add_data(str_replace($source . '/', '', $base_name . '/' . $file), file_get_contents($file));
                            }
                        }

                        $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->db->dbprefix('sharing_link') . ' SET sharing_download = sharing_download + 1 WHERE sharing_link_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_id'] . ' AND sharing_link_user_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_user_id']);

                        $this->zip->download($base_name . '.zip');
                    } elseif (file_exists($filepath)) {

                        //$this->db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->db->dbprefix('sharing_link') . ' SET sharing_download = sharing_download + 1 WHERE sharing_link_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_id'] . ' AND sharing_link_user_id = ' . $path_info['sharing_link_user_id']);
                        //Load captcha code view    

                        redirect(site_url('download_shared_link/download_v2/' . $org_path));
                        exit();

                        /* header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filepath) . '"');
                          header('Expires: 0');
                          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                          header('Pragma: public');
                          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
                          flush(); // Flush system output buffer
                          readfile($filepath);
                          exit; */
                    }
                } else {
                    //$this->db->where('sharing_link_id', $path_info['sharing_link_id']);
                    //$this->db->delete('sharing_link');
                    //redirect(site_url());
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>This Link Not Active !</p>";
            }
        } else {
            redirect(site_url());
        }
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        $this->db->where('sharing_link_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('sharing_link');
        redirect(site_url('Download_shared_link'));
    }

    public function active_inactive($id, $mode) {
        $this->db->where('sharing_link_id', $id);
        $data = array(
            'sharing_link_active' => $mode,
        );
        $this->db->update('sharing_link', $data);
        redirect(site_url('Download_shared_link'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching from `file_get_contents` to `fopen`.

It should use much less memory.

If you still keep hitting the limits, you may need adjusting your server resources.

Comment: Every usage of file_get_contents Is wrapped in `if false` So this Is not the case...

Comment: This problem occurs when i try to download file around 1 gb small file like 200 mb or less than 1gb is download perfectly.

Comment: still same prodiger i switch file_get_contents to fopen